# try to restore a sql dump file larger than 10 GB

Tags: sql, sql-server, xampp, mysql

I am trying to restore a sql dump file that is 13G big. I firstly used phpAdmin in xampp, it said the size was too big. Then i used big dump, still I got the error message that " I can not seek in xx.sql". I found online that it means the file is too big.
Then I start to use command line.
mysql -u username -p database < location/to/your/dump.sql
seems it is working because it asked for password, and I directly pressed enter because I do not have a password. 
And now i can see the "_" keeps flashing, i am assuming that this means it is working. BUt there is no way I can check to make sure, and it is taking a while already.

Is there a way to make sure it is working? I really appreciate your help!!
TJ

Answer (score 9):

Another way to restore files with the `mysql` command line client is like this:

```
$ mysql -u username -p database 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2933685
--8<-- snip --8<--

mysql> source location/to/your/dump.sql
```

The `source` command will read the dump file and apply it to the server just like the `<` redirection operator, but with two differences:  you will see continuous "x rows affected" messages scrolling by, giving you some indication that progress is actually occurring.  The down-side of this method is that, unlike the method using `<` redirection, if there are any errors in the dump file, the command line client will just try to keep going, which is not always what you want.  Still, it might be a viable approach.

Or... the way you're doing it now, if you can see the connection in the processlist, check the value for `Sleep`.  If the value is constantly 0, then some kind of activity is occurring.

Comment: This has worked well for me. I have a few databases and they are all over 1GB backups. My largest is 12GB. This method imported the data very quickly, under 15 minutes. Before, I was using MySQL -u root -p  database < backup.sql. But it was timing out and not completing the import. As stated with the source function there is an on-screen display of progress. That helps a lot to know where the program is stopping. It showed me that I had a corrupt table as to why the import was failing on one of my systems.

Answer (score 0):

I restore similar sized files

1. Takes me about 4-5 hours, can be more depends on the nature of keys and constraints you have
2. You can always check the process list to see if it works.
3. tail -f the mysql general log, and make sure it logs any query. that's the easiest way to see if it is working or not. **A caveat, this slows everything even more, by 100% +**

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!! I checked the process list, the command line program is in the process list, but it is not using any CPU.

Comment: But i dont understand the 3rd tip you suggested. How do I check the logs?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this technique

After connecting to the remote MySql database…

- Generate a query to create table schema, procedures and functions of the source DB
- Generate a query to find all indexes of all tables except foreign key constraints of the - source DB
- Generate a query to drop all the indexes found in step 2
- Generate a query to insert all data of the source DB
- Generate a query to create all the indexes found in step 2
- Write all queries in the above order in one .sql file which is your new MySql backup. Zip it using LZ4 compression.
- Now just restore the DB from this file using normal restore utility of MySql.

Ref: http://axiomnext.com/blog/how-to-restore-large-mysql-database-faster/